# Why does a property-wrapped member list display unexpected values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, python-decorators

Take this simple example class:

```
class vec:
   def __init__(self,v=(0,0,0,0)):
       self.v = list(v)

   @property
   def x(self):
       return self.v[0]

   @x.setter
   def set_x(self, val):
       self.v[0] = val
```

...and this usage:

```
>> a = vec([1,2,3,4])
>> a.v
[1,2,3,4]
>> a.x
1
>> a.x = 55
>> a.x
55
>> a.v
[1,2,3,4]
```

Why do the member array (specifically, `self.v[0]`) and the reported property value disagree? If it's not in `self.v`, where is the altered property value coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use new-style class. And the name of the setter should be `x`, not `set_x`.

```
class vec(object): # <-----
   def __init__(self,v=(0,0,0,0)):
       self.v = list(v)

   @property
   def x(self):
       return self.v[0]

   @x.setter
   def x(self, val): # <--------
       self.v[0] = val
```

According to [`property` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> Return a property attribute for **new-style classes (classes that derive from object)**.

If you don't use new-style class, `a.x = ...` creates a new attribute `x` instead of calling the setter.